# How should I parse Request.GetBufferlessInputStream()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an upload control for ASP.NET, and I need to work with Request.GetBufferlessInputStream()

This returns the raw unprocessed request stream. Is there a built in way to parse the content of this stream, stripping out headers such as the example I've copied below.

If not what is the best approach to parsing the file?

```
-----------------------------13166267887793
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="ABigFile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution came from inspecting how it's done in System.Web, and adapting to my needs. The core functionality is found in an internal class called HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser. The system for processing the input stream is written up here:

http://blog.appsoftware.com/2014/03/aspnet-file-uploader-with-signalr.html

Comment: any chance that you have saved your parser in github?